ffmpeg and .srt file with delayed subtitles
I have an .avi file from a miniDV camera and an .srt file with subtitles extracted from it.
I run the avi file through Avisynth.
The .srt file starts at 37m48s:
1
00:37:47,840 --> 00:37:48,400
08/13/2011
15:45:36

2
00:37:48,400 --> 00:37:49,400
08/13/2011
15:45:37

I convert it like this:
ffmpeg.exe -avisynth_flags +all -i "input.avs" -i "input.srt" -map 0:v -map 0:a? -map 1:s? -c:v libx264 -crf 17 -c:a aac -b:a 192k -c:s mov_text -metadata:s:s:0 title="Timecode" -disposition:s:0 0 "output.mp4"
But in the resulting file the subtitles start from the very beginning. Is it possible to write a command for ffmpeg so that the subtitles are at their time positions?
